# Using InputView property on iOS

Tags: ios, uitextview, inputview

I have developed a custom keyboard with a view and a view controller.  In my application's main view controller, I hold a property for the custom keyboard view controller.

I have a `textView` which should get input from the custom keyboard. The `customKeyboard` property is the view controller for the custom keyboard.

I put the following in `viewDidLoad` of the main application's `viewController`.

```
self.textView.inputView = self.customKeyboard.view;
```

The standard system keyboard appears when I make the `textView` first responder.  IB appears to be linking my textView property to the UI component.  What do I need to do to get the custom keyboard to appear?

Comment: maybe instead of dot notation you can try [textView setInput:customKeyboard.view]. Maybe also check to make sure that your customKeyboard is properly getting initalized and retained. Hope this helps

Comment: The two are equivalent, using setX: or .x= call the same code

Answer (score 5):

Try some calls to `[self.textView reloadInputViews]`. If that doesn't work, try to subclass `UITextView` and override its `inputView` method such that it always returns the view you want to use as the custom keyboard.